# How to properly output variables that may contain single quote or double quotes using Template Literals?

Tags: javascript

I output a variable to data attribute using template literals:

```
let someHtml = `<div><span data-something='${dataVariable}'>Some Text</span></div>
```

The problem is that the `dataVariable` is a string that may contain single quote or double quotes, and then when I append the HTML it breaks.

When I use `'${dataVariable}'` the HTML breaks for any string that contains single quote, and if I try to change it to `"${dataVariable}"` it then breaks for any string that contains double quotes because it closes the first quotation mark

How to properly do it?

Comment: Build your HTML using Element objects then assign to the `dataset` collection, eg `fooElement.dataset.bar = 'A "B" C';`

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can create your own sanitisation logic to escape/remove the duplicated quotes, but `dataset` already has this functionality impemented more reliably.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment (For anyone seeing, my comment was "I assume there is no neat way to do it using my metod?").

@RoryMcCrossan, would that work even if it is unknown what does the variable contain? i.e. `fooElement.dataset.bar = 'A "B" C';` or `fooElement.dataset.bar = 'A'B'C';`?

Comment: So long as the string is valid, then yes. But the string `'A'B'C'` is not valid. You would have to use `'A\'B\'C'` or `"A'B'C"` instead

Comment: Alright so in my case it would still not solve part of the problem, because I get many rows from the backend which can change. So I can't have a single line `fooElement.dataset.bar = 'A "B" C'` or `fooElement.dataset.bar = "A 'B' C"` because it always changes. IS there a way to use a single line which will take care of both scnearios? Or I need to escape it in the backend first, or somehow in the JavaScript side before setting the data attribute?

Comment: Is it not held in a variable already? In that case just pass the variable to `dataset.bar` and it will work fine. The above syntax is only relevant for string literals